# Причина выброса EOFException из readUTF()

Tags: java

Здравствуйте.
К вопросу в заголовке могу добавить только следующее: заведомо известно, что читаемый бинарник был записан средствами java, следовательно расхождений в таблицах символов быть не может (записана и ожидается modified-UTF), и что на текущем этапе в файле должна быть записана именно строка (с неё начинаются данные в файле, если конкретнее). А исключение всё равно выбрасывается. Какие ещё могут быть причины? Файл получаем из файлдиалога, файл не путой, с ним проблем точно нет.

Код:

```
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(fis);
// ...
dis.readUTF(); // Здесь инициируется исключение.
// ...
fis.close();
dis.close();
```

Comment: погуглите utf и utf + bom

возможно у вас файл в первом формате в то время когда в вашей системе по умолчанию исопльзуется второй (в котором длинее заголовок)

p.s. нельзя быть на 100% уверенным в файле. попробуйте с вашей же программы записать аналогичные данные в файл а потом прочитать их обратно (данные сформируйте сами если это возможно), можете попробовать для начала на более простых данных а-ля "123"

Comment: @Артём Быков Т.е., говоря коротко, формат файла не соответствовал ожиданиям.

Answer (score 2):

Чудес не бывает. Вероятнее всего ошибка была допущена при записи. Внимательно ознакомьтесь с описанием метода [DataInput.readUTF()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/DataInput.html#readUTF%28%29) и проверьте, что содержимое файла действительно соответствует ожиданиям. Как минимум стоит убедиться, что длина строки, записанной в файл, соответствует длине, указанной в двух байтах, предшествующей строке.

Comment: а как можно проверить содержимое файла? Бинарник ведь.

Comment: @Артём Быков Что такое байт знаете? Если да, то разобраться с бинарником для вас не составит труда. Формат файла, насколько я понимаю, вам либо известен, либо вы можете его выяснить путем изучения кода, который этот файл пишет.

Comment: Скорее всего тот кто пишет не закрыл файл как положено и читаемая строка осталась обрезанной.

Comment: @Артём Быков описание формата файла генерируемого `DataOutputStream` [здесь](http://mindprod.com/jgloss/binaryformats.html)

Answer (score 2):

Откройте файл в любом HEX редакторе и проверьте внимательно содержимое. Чаще всего имеются артифакты.